# A proper integral which can't be evaluated if improper

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

If you would like to find the electric potential of a conducting disc in space you would have several approaches.

1. Laplace Equation.(not so great approach though!)
2. Finding the charge on a conducting ellipsoid(this problem itself has many appraoches,so diverse!)then you take the limit when the ellipsoid becomes a disk.so you have the charge density and must integrate to get potential.
3. Use a conducting rod as image charge and again taking a limit.

Its so fascinating that doing *1* leads to an infinite series (infinite series), *2* leads to a though integral and the (calculus), and *3* leads to finding the Real part of a very big Ln (arithmetic). And all these will give the same answer as they should. Three things so diffrent in "shape" but they turn out to be the same!

My situation is: I want to evaluate the integral which I got while doing $2$. Also I'd like to evaluate $3$ and know the real part and imaginary part of that gigantic Ln. (it would be an $X+iY$ representation.)!

[image: the integral]
[image: the Ln]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Even after editing there is still no question. The integral can be evaluated using the complete elliptic integral of the first kind, try e.g. Wolfram Alpha

Comment: thats the point!it can be made simpler than complete elliptic integral!and by the way of you look at it that way 90% of integral quesions in this site can be evaluated by wolfram.and as for the second question:that Ln(..) equals X+iY .find X and Y.dont you see?every complex function can be represented that way.this Ln again gets simplified.It should(I know it from the physics of the problem)

Comment: at least tell me what you think!dont you get the queston or is it not solvable?Im sure the integral can be simplyfied and as for the Ln(..) whats the problem?

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle{\large%
?
\equiv
\int_{0}^{a}
{{\rm d}x \over \sqrt{x^{2} + c^{2}\,}\ \sqrt{a^{2} - x^{2}\,}}\,,
\quad a > 0}$.

With the change $x \equiv a\,\sin\left(\theta\right)$, we
get
$\displaystyle{%
? = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{{\rm d}\theta \over \sqrt{a^{2}\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right) + c^{2}}}
}$.
Now, we use la identity
$\displaystyle{%
\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right) = {1 - \cos\left(2\theta\right) \over 2}
.\quad}$ $?$ becomes:

\begin{align}
?
&=
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{{\rm d}\theta
 \over
 \sqrt{a^{2}\left\lbrack 1 - \cos\left(2\theta\right)\right\rbrack/2 + c^{2}}}
=
\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}2\,}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{{\rm d}\theta
 \over
 \sqrt{a^{2} + 2c^{2} - a^{2}\cos\left(2\theta\right)}}
\\[3mm]&=
{\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}2\,} \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi}
{{\rm d}\theta
 \over
 \sqrt{a^{2} + 2c^{2} - a^{2}\cos\left(\theta\right)}}
=
{\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}2\,} \over 2}\,
{2 \over \sqrt{\left(a^{2} + 2c^{2}\right) + a^{2}\,}}\,
{\bf E}\,\left(%
\sqrt{2c^{2} \over \left(a^{2} + 2c^{2}\right) + a^{2}}
\right)
\end{align}

where ${\bf E}\left(k\right) \equiv {\rm E}\left(\pi/2,k\right)$ is the Complete Elliptic Integral of the Second Kind.
$\displaystyle{{\rm E}\left(\varphi,k\right)
\equiv
\int_{0}^{\varphi}
 \sqrt{1 - k^{2}\sin^{2}\left(\alpha\right)\,}\ {\rm d}\alpha}$ is the Elliptic Integral of the Second Kind. In the derivation we used the identity:
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}{{\rm d}x \over \sqrt{\alpha \pm \beta\cos\left(x\right)\,}}
=
{2 \over \alpha + \beta}\,
{\bf E}\,\left(\sqrt{2\beta \over \alpha + \beta\,}\,\right)\,,
\qquad
\alpha > \beta > 0
$$

$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\
\color{#ff0000}{\large\quad\int_{0}^{a}
{{\rm d}x \over \sqrt{x^{2} + c^{2}\,}\ \sqrt{a^{2} - x^{2}\,}}
=
{1 \over \sqrt{a^{2} + c^{2}\,}}\,
{\bf \color{#000000}{E}}\,\left(\left\vert c\right\vert \over \sqrt{a^{2} + c^{2}\,}\right)\,,\quad a > 0,\ c\not= 0\quad}
\\ \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$